# How do I simulate from GAR(1) model in R?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, simulation, autoregressive

I want to simulate an GAR(1) model, defined by
$(1-\alpha \beta )^{\delta }X_{t} = Z_{t}$
, where $X_t$ is a time series, and $Z_t$ is a white noise process. How do I simulate from this model in `R` with
$\alpha=0.8$, $\delta=0.8$ and $\sigma^2 = 1.0$?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does GAR stand for? What is the value of $\beta$? Is this supposed to be autoregressive? If so, where are the lags of $X_t$?

Comment: Should $\beta$ be the "lag function" $L$ instead?